# Morse code encoder/decoder with playback ability

Tags: java, morse-code

recently I wanted to create a morse encoder/decoder with playback ability, the program needs `java version >= 11` to run.

the program requires a couple of `jar`s :

- `com.google.common.collect.BiMap`
- `javazoom.jl.player.Player`

I used the `BiMap` for the following reason:

> A bimap (or "bidirectional map") is a map that preserves the uniqueness of its values as well as that of its keys. This constraint enables bimaps to support an "inverse view", which is another bimap containing the same entries as this bimap but with reversed keys and values.[ref](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html)

As many online Morse translators, use the character `'/'` or a `','` to be translated into space I used the `'\t'`.

Structure wise I used the Singleton Design pattern To allow the user of having a limited amount of objects thus there is no need to create an object to encode/decode if it already exists.

The program features the following:

1. Flexible thus it can read from the desired database.
2. Compatible with all kinds of allowed `CharSet` backed by java(when using the right charset to read a certain file).
3. Audio playback to help people learn to understand morse code by hearing!.
4. Ability to write results into a file by the desired path.
5. The program takes regex into consideration when it comes to reading the database file as the regex would act as a separator between the actual letter and the sequence of dots and dashes.

**So here is the Code:**

```
import com.google.common.collect.BiMap;
import com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap;
import javazoom.jl.decoder.JavaLayerException;
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static com.google.common.collect.Maps.unmodifiableBiMap;

/**
 * This class represents Encoder and Decoder for Morse code.
 * @author  Kazem Aljalabi.
 */
public final class Morse {

    private Path dataBaseFile;
    private BiMap<String, String> data;
    private Charset cs = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    private String charSeparationRegex = " ";

    //Singleton Pattern via Lazy Instantiation = private constructor + static object that will be created once!.
    private static Morse defaultObj, pathObj, objWithSeparator, objWithCharSet;

    /**
     * This Method creates a class instance of type {@link Morse} if not created before else return the already created object.
     * @return a class instance of type {@link Morse}.
     */
    public static Morse getInstance() {
        if (null == defaultObj)
            defaultObj = new Morse();
        return defaultObj;
    }

    /**
     * This Method creates a class instance of type {@link Morse} if not created before else return the already created object.
     * @param dataBaseFile the path to the database which contains the actual decoding and encoding table of the morse code.
     * @return a class instance of type {@link Morse} linked with a database of user's choice via a {@link Path}.
     */
    public static Morse getInstance(final Path dataBaseFile) {
        if (null == pathObj)
            pathObj = new Morse(dataBaseFile);
        return pathObj;
    }


    /**
     * This Method creates a class instance of type {@link Morse} if not created before else return the already created object.
     * @param dataBaseFile the {@link Path} to the database which contains the actual decoding and encoding table of the morse code.
     * @param separator the regex which will act as a separator between the actual letter and its representation in morse code.
     * @return a class instance of type {@link Morse} linked with database path and a separator.
     */
    public static Morse getInstance(final Path dataBaseFile, final String separator) {
        if (null == objWithSeparator)
            objWithSeparator = new Morse(dataBaseFile, separator);
        return objWithSeparator;
    }
    
    /**
     * This Method creates a class instance of type {@link Morse} if not created before else return the already created object.
     * @param dataBaseFile the path to the database which contains the actual decoding and encoding table of the morse code.
     * @param separator the regex which will act as a separator between the actual letter and its representation in morse code.
     * @param cs the {@link Charset} in which the database is written with.
     * @return a class instance of type {@link Morse} linked with the database with a specific path, charset, and separator.
     */
    public static Morse getInstance(final Path dataBaseFile, final String separator, final Charset cs) {
        if (null == objWithCharSet)
            objWithCharSet = new Morse(dataBaseFile, separator, cs);
        return objWithCharSet;
    }

    /**
     * @param dataBaseFile path to the new dataBaseFile to be set.
     */
    public void setDataBaseFile(Path dataBaseFile) {
        this.dataBaseFile = dataBaseFile;
        checkForDataBase();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor to create a class instance of type {@link Morse} with a default database called "Code.txt" placed in the same dir with the class.
     */
    private Morse() {
        dataBaseFile = Paths.get(Morse.class.getResource( "Morse.class" ).getPath()).toAbsolutePath().normalize().getParent().resolve("Code.txt");
        checkForDataBase();
    }


    /**
     * Constructor creates a class instance of type {@link Morse} with a custom database provided by the user via a valid path.
     * @param dataBaseFile the path to the database which contains the actual decoding and encoding table of the morse code.
     */
    private Morse(final Path dataBaseFile) {
        this.dataBaseFile = dataBaseFile;
        checkForDataBase();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor creates a class instance of type {@link Morse} with a custom database with a specific separator provided by the user via a valid path.
     * @param dataBaseFile the {@link Path} to the database which contains the actual decoding and encoding table of the morse code.
     * @param separator the regex which will act as a separator between the actual letter and its representation in morse code.
     */
    private Morse(final Path dataBaseFile, final String separator) {
        this (dataBaseFile);
        assert separator != null;
        if ( checkForRegexValidity(separator) && !separator.contains(".") && !separator.contains("_") ) //those are reserved to the morse code!
            this.charSeparationRegex = separator;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor creates a class instance of type {@link Morse} with a custom database with a specific separator provided by the user via a valid path.
     * The database file is written in a specific CharSet.
     * @param dataBaseFile the path to the database which contains the actual decoding and encoding table of the morse code.
     * @param separator the regex which will act as a separator between the actual letter and its representation in morse code.
     * @param cs the {@link Charset} in which the database is written with.
     */
    private Morse(final Path dataBaseFile, final String separator, final Charset cs) {
        this (dataBaseFile, separator);
        this.cs = cs;
    }


    /**
     * Method to check the existence of database path.
     */
    private void checkForDataBase () {
        if (!Files.exists(dataBaseFile))
            System.exit(1);
        data = unmodifiableBiMap(populateFromDataBase());
    }

    /**
     * Method to check if the separator provided by the user is a valid regex.
     * @param regex database separator provided by the user.
     * @return true if the regex is valid else false.
     */
    private boolean checkForRegexValidity (String regex) {
        PatternSyntaxException flag = null;
        try {
            Pattern.compile(regex);
        } catch (PatternSyntaxException exception) { flag=exception; }
        return flag == null;
    }

    /**
     * Method to populate the Database from the database {@link java.io.File}.
     * @return a {@link BiMap} which contains the encoding/decoding schema of the Morse code based on the database file.
     */
    private BiMap<String, String> populateFromDataBase () {
        List<String> encodingSchema = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            encodingSchema = Files.readAllLines(dataBaseFile, cs);
        } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        //To prevent the empty of being inserted inside the Hash we need to filter it out!
        return encodingSchema.stream().filter(s -> !s.equals(""))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        e -> e.replaceAll(charSeparationRegex," ").strip().split("\\s+")[0]
                        ,  e -> e.replaceAll(charSeparationRegex," ").strip().split("\\s+")[1]
                        , (e1, e2) -> e2
                        , HashBiMap::create)
                );
    }

    /**
     * Method which will write a specific message to a given file.
     * @param data The data to be written to a file. the data can be an already encoded message or the decoded message of an already encoded message!.
     * @param resultsPath the path where the results would be written, if it doesn't exist it will be created.
     */
    public void writeResultsToFile (String data, Path resultsPath) {
        try {
            Files.writeString(resultsPath, data, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
        } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    /**
     * Method to decode a given Message based on the given database and the morse code logic.
     * @param message to be decoded assuming that the message contains only '_' and '.', assuming that the message given contains no foreign chars that don't exist in the database given.
     * @return a decoded version of the provided message.
     */
    public String decodeMessage(String message) {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (var str : message.strip().split("\t"))
            builder.append(decodeHelper(str)).append(" ");

        return builder.toString().strip();
    }

    /**
     * A helper method to decode One Word at a time.
     * @param word which consists of '_' and '.' which will be encoded accordingly to the given database.
     * @return a valid decoded word.
     */
    private StringBuilder decodeHelper (String word) {
        return Arrays.stream(word.split(" "))
                .collect(StringBuilder::new
                        , (builder, s) -> builder.append(data.inverse().getOrDefault(s, " "))
                        , StringBuilder::append
                );
    }

    /**
     * Method to encode a certain message based on the provided database.
     * @param message to be encoded assuming that the message given contains no foreign chars that don't exist in the database given.
     * @return an encoded version to the provided message which consists of only '_' and '.'.
     */
    public String encodeMessage (String message) {

        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (var str : message.toUpperCase().strip().split("")) {
            builder.append(data.getOrDefault(str, ""));
            if (!str.equals(" "))
                builder.append(" ");
            else
                builder.append("\t");//insert tap to tell when word ends!.
        }
        return builder.toString().strip();
    }

    /**
     * Method to play the actual sound of a certain message while being encoded.
     * @param data to be encoded.
     */
    public void encodeAndPlayAudio (String data) {
        var encoded = encodeMessage(data).split("\t");
        var tabsNumber = encoded.length-1;

        for (var c : encoded) {
            playAudio(c);

            if (tabsNumber-- > 0){
                System.out.print("\t");
                try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {  }
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    /**
     * @param filename of the soundtrack to be played.
     */
    private void playMp3 (String filename) {
        try (var fis = new FileInputStream(Morse.class.getResource(filename).getPath())) {
            new Player(fis).play();
        } catch (IOException | JavaLayerException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    /**
     * Method to decide which soundtrack will get played based on the current char.
     * @param encodeMessage which will be played.
     */
    private void playAudio (String encodeMessage) {
        for (var c : encodeMessage.strip().toCharArray()){
            if (c == '.')
                playMp3("di.mp3");
            else if (c == '_')
                playMp3("dah.mp3");

            System.out.print(c);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Morse morse = (Morse) o;
        return dataBaseFile.equals(morse.dataBaseFile) &&
                data.equals(morse.data);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() { return Objects.hash(dataBaseFile, data); }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Morse{" +
                "dataBaseFile=" + dataBaseFile +
                ", data=" + data +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**DataBase sample `code.txt`** (of course this can be extended when desired) :

```
A   ._
B   _...
C   _._.
D   _..
E   .
F   .._.
G   __.
H   ....
I   ..
J   .___
K   _._
L   ._..
M   __
N   _.
O   ___
P   .__.
Q   __._
R   ._.
S   ...
T   _
U   .._
V   ..._
W   .__
X   _.._
Y   _.__
Z   __..
1   .____
2   ..___
3   ...__
4   ...._
5   .....
6   _....
7   __...
8   ___..
9   ____.
0   _____
```

**The user main would look like this** :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var obj = Morse.getInstance();
        System.out.println(obj.encodeMessage("cool java"));
        obj.encodeAndPlayAudio("cool java");

    }
}
```

**The audio files can be found in Wikipedia**

1. dot sound which is basically an `'E'` can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:E_morse_code.ogg)!
2. dash sound which is basically a `'T'` can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:T_morse_code.ogg)!

**What to review:**

I would like a style, design, and functional review. What is done good, what should be done better or differently? What alternative solution would you propose?

Please note that this project is made for fun and educational purposes and is not a part of a university assignment!.

As explained by @Sᴀᴍ Onᴇᴌᴀ in the comments I shall not update my code to incorporate feedback from answers "doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review" thus here is the current status on my [Github](https://github.com/hakunamatata97k/Morse-Encoder-Decoder/blob/master/Morse_Code/src/MorseResolver/Morse.java).

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) as well as  [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Comment: cool, I didn't know that! but you could just comment that you didn't have to force an edit. lol. but thnx for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getInstance` methods are severely limiting the class and are a source of potential bugs. There is no reason that it shouldn't be possible, for example, to create two objects with that access two different database files:

```
Morse morse1 = Morse.getInstance(Paths.get("file1"));
Morse morse2 = Morse.getInstance(Paths.get("file2"));
```

However in this example, `morse2` unexpectedly doesn't use `"file2"`, instead is the same instance as `morse1` which uses `"file1"`.

(EDIT: You should avoid setters, if you can. Immutable classes are usually preferable. If you, for example, want to change databases at runtime, it's preferable to create a new object using that other database, than changing an existing object.)

---

The constructors should be structured differently, so that all the logic/validation only happens in a single one and the other constructors only call that one constructor with the default values.

EDIT: Currently you have two constructors that call `checkForDataBase()`, and another one that validates the separator. Instead you should have a single "main" constructor (probably `Morse(final Path dataBaseFile, final String separator, final Charset cs)`), than contains all the validation and have the others call that one using the default values for the missing parameters. For eaxmple:

```
private final static String DEFAULT_SEPARATOR = " ";
private final static CharSet DEFAULT_CHARSET = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

public Morse(final Path dataBaseFile, final String separator, final Charset cs) {
   // All validation and setting instance fields here
}

public Morse() {
  this(defaultDatabaseFile());
  // or: this(defaultDatabaseFile(), DEFAULT_SEPARATOR, DEFAULT_CHARSET)
}

public Morse(final Path dataBaseFile) {
  this(dataBaseFile, DEFAULT_SEPARATOR);
  // or: this(dataBaseFile, DEFAULT_SEPARATOR, DEFAULT_CHARSET)
}

public Morse(final Path dataBaseFile, final String separator) {
  this(dataBaseFile, separator, DEFAULT_CHARSET);
}
```

---

Retrieving the default database file seems a bit convoluted, especially with the hard-coded class file name `"Morse.class"`, which easily can be overlooked, if the class is ever renamed.

Unless I'm mistaken (I don't like handling resources), it should be possible with:

```
Paths.get(Morse.class.getResource("../Code.txt").toURI());
```

---

The `assert` keyword is not for validating parameters. It is used during development to catch states than should never occur. `assert` would normally be disabled at production  runtime. Instead use [`Objects.requireNonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-).

---

`separator.contains(".")` is an unreliable way to check if a regular expression matches a period, because it is special character in regular expressions that matches any character. It probably would be better to check for `\.` (`"\\."` as a Java string). Or maybe not let the user directly assign a regular expression as the separator at all, but an array of chars/strings instead, from which you build a regular expression.

---

Using `System.exit(1)` inside a utility class like this is unexpected and thus a bad idea. You should be throwing an exception here, which you could catch in `main()` and possibly use `System.exit()` there.

---

`checkForRegexValidity` seems unnesserily complex. There is no need to store the thrown exception. Just directly return `true` or `false`:

```
private boolean checkForRegexValidity (String regex) {
    try {
        Pattern.compile(regex);
        return true;
    } catch (PatternSyntaxException exception) { 
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

When encountering an exception when reading the database file, don't just print the stack trace and otherwise ignore the error. Personally I'd just let the exception go through and catch it outside this class. Actually you could just drop `checkForDataBase` and just have the IOException due to the missing file go through.

---

During filling the map you are unnecessarily cleaning up and splitting the lines twice. With an additional `.map` step in the stream that can be avoided:

```
return encodingSchema.stream().filter(s -> !s.equals(""))
      .map(e -> e.replaceAll(charSeparationRegex," ").strip().split("\\s+"))
      .filter(e -> e.length < 2) // also skip invalid lines
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    e -> e[0]
                    ,  e -> e[1]
                    , (e1, e2) -> e2
                    , HashBiMap::create)
            );
```

---

I don't really see the point in using a `BiMap` here. If you where constantly adding or removing entries from it, then it would be certainly be a good idea, however in this case the map is static so I'd just create two normal maps.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I took your suggestions into my consideration. in my code i replaced assertion, with `Objects.requireNonNull` and I would rather use `getPath()` instead of using `toUrl()`  thus I won't have to catch exceptions in my constructor.

Comment: please provide me with a better explanation about what you mean with "The constructors should be structured differently".


please provide me with a better explanation about what you mean with "The constructors should be structured differently". 



about what you mentioned about creating a second object for a different database I think there is no need for having a new object while I can add a database setter that would resolve that problem in my opinion.

Comment: I just added the setter which I already wrote but didn't upload because I thought it was not needed.

Comment: @Studenaccount4 Updated.

Comment: using the `HashBiMap` was very helpful for me because of the `inverse()` in the decoding where one would need to get key by value which is not supported by the default hashmap. and about the regex well checking for the dot and the underscore is the easiest thing and yet gets the job done without getting into trouble of creating the regex myself based on a string given by the user.
I linked the GitHub link and i would really appreciate it if you look at it :) thanks for the efforts taken to write this review.

Comment: later on, I added a hashmap to act as a "set" it will check if the object has been created it will return it to the user. due to the fact that one cant retrieve elements from a Set, I used hashmap with the object itself as key and value.

Comment: in my opinion, I can't see a situation where `filter(e -> e.length < 2)` would be triggered, and placing 2 would result in an empty map. changing the 2 to 3 would solve it but still can't imagine a situation where this could be triggered.